# Get IP address of the server sending a request via html form

Tags: php, html

I want to get the IP address of the server sending request via HTML FORM.

I made a test like this:

**HTML FORM (form.html in server 1):**

```
<form action="URL_OF_SERVER2/rec.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP FILE: (rec.php)**

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'<br><br>'; // To get referal URL
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // To get IP Address
?>
```

But when i tested, i get my own IP Address and not the one of the server.

**Second try:**

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'<br><br>'; // To get referal URL
$result = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo gethostbyname($result['host']); // To get IP Address
?>
```

But this not get real IP but the one of cloudflare for example, i want make same system as perfectmoney, you put your real IP on your dashboard to accept only request coming from, even if you are behind cloudflare, perfectmoney detect the real IP.

On my dashboard i can put IPs by range: 127.0.0.1/24 , 127.0.0.* ... to accept only requests coming from and even if the domain name is behind cloudflare or another similar services.

Comment: your *own IP Address* is `'REMOTE_ADDR'` in relation to your local web server

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` is the server that executes the script's address. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` is the client address (the one that sent the request to the server from the server's point of view.
See the [$_SERVER array documentation](http://php.net/manual/bg/reserved.variables.server.php) for more info.

Comment: There misunderstanding sir, i want get the IP address of the referer server and not my own server.

Comment: You can get the referer from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but in order to get the IP address of the referer, you must send the request from it. Instead you're executing the form from your browser, which is why you're getting your own IP address. To do that, you can use a php script on server1 that utilizes `curl` to POST to the second server. I'm afraid it's not trivial. See the examples here:  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: I don't want it from URL, please check my edited post please :)

Answer (score 0):

> address of the server sending request

The server doesn't send a request. The browser sends a request, and the server sends a response.

If you want the IP of the browser sending a request, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

If you want the IP of the server sending a response, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.

Note: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` may not actually represent the browser's IP if there are any proxies in the way.

Update: If you want the IP address of the REFERER server, you will have to do your own DNS lookup.

```
$data = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
print_r(dns_get_record($data['host']));
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 270
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 172.217.9.68
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => www.google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 14
            [type] => AAAA
            [ipv6] => 2607:f8b0:4009:816::2004
        )

)
```

Note however that this is unreliable, as `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can easily be faked.

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` get too server ip with form sending a request throue `GET` method or only `POST`?

Comment: Both. (Plus HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, and whatever others there are...)

Comment: There misunderstanding sir, i want get the IP address of the referer server and not my own server.

Comment: Ah! Ok, that was not clear in your question. I will update.